# Deploy VueJS App in a sub-directory or sub-path

Tags: linux, vue.js, nginx, vuejs2, vue-router

I’m experiencing problems deploying a Vue JS app built using the Webpack CLi to work.

If uploaded in a root directory everything renders fine, but inside a subfolder, all the links break.

I want deploy VueJS App to this url :
https://event.domain.net/webinar

I have added publicPath in vue.config.js :

```
var path = require(‘path’)
module.exports = {
   publicPath: ‘./’
}
```

But only the css and js folders point to the path /webinar.

For assets, fonts and others still point to the subdomain https://event.domain.net.

[CSS and JS point to path /webinar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v84P5.jpg)

[Asset, fonts still point to subdomain https://event.domain.net/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lByn7.jpg)

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wMzs.png)

Answer (score 2):

use value of publicPath as `/webinar` that should work.

More details are here https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

you can configure publicPath even based on environment.

Comment: @Argan did this answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

[Sagar Rabadiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455420/sagar-rabadiya) pointed you to the right link:

1. create a file called `vue.config.js` in the project root (where your `package.json` is located).
2. prompt the following code snippet inside:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'? '/your-sub-directory/' : '/'
}
```

and save the file.

3. Open a terminal and navigate to your project, then run `npm run build` to generate a production build from it.
4. As soon as the production build has been generated, copy the contents from it and paste it in the sub-directory you created in the root folder. For example, if you use Apache, the default root directory is the `htdocs` folder. I've also created a virtual host on the server, maybe you also need to do this.
5. Open the browser and type the address where your sub-directory lives. For example: `http://your-server-url:your-port/your-sub-directory/` Your should see your app now.